# MySQL Query sort that has same value in two fields

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
  t1.f1 AS val1,
  SUM(t2.f1) AS val2
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.f2 = t1.f2
GROUP BY t1.f2
```

Which results:

```
va1    val2  
25      8         
10      10
25      25
10      1
```

And would like to have a way to sort the same value from two fields, with a MySQL query, the data on the following format:

```
va1    val2       
10      10
25      25
```

Grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

extend your query by

```
HAVING t1.f1=SUM(t2.f1)
ORDER BY t1.f1
```